# I want to insert multiple activity data into same table rows in database in SQlite. Please Tell me How can I do it

Tags: android

I've made the multiple pages to register the people account in my application. But when I try to insert data ,the data inserted but in different rows .Might be it is the matter of passing id of table. The logic is making way into my mind but idk how to implement it.

I'm stuck into implementing the logic.

Comment: Can you please explain with example? Inserting any data in to the database table totally depends on the table structure you create. If you have additional columns to add relevant data, you can add them. You will just need to use the same row id for inserting. Also, just see to it that while adding you do not overwrite the existing columns.

Comment: what you have done can you show us please